# Feature testing with Capybara: An error occurred in an after hook ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am beginner in Rails and I am trying to write test for functionality "edit user" with capybara, but each time I get the following error:

> An error occurred in an after hook
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
>
> occurred at /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'

Here is my testing code:

```
context 'when wrong parameters' do
          scenario 'checkout name is mandatory' do
            fill_in 'name', with: ''
            fill_in 'email', with: ''
            3.times { wait_for_ajax }
            click_button '保存'
            expect(page).to have_current_path('/users/1')
            expect(page).to have_content 'お名前を入力してください'
          end
```

And here is my spec_helper.rb and rails_helper.rb

```
    require 'factory_girl_rails'

    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
        expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
      end

      config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
        mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
      end
    end


ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'support/authentication_helper'
require 'capybara'
require 'support/wait_helper'
require 'rake'
require 'support/feature_testing_functions_helper'

Rails.application.load_tasks
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include AuthenticationHelper

  config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :feature
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, type: :feature
  config.include WaitHelper, type: :feature
  config.include FeatureTestingFunctions, type: :feature
  Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
  config.before :suite do
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:setup'].invoke
  end
  config.after :each do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

I have no idea why this error came out, is there any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what the issue is - You have some sort of element load in an after hook.  You don't show any after hooks in any of the code you have posted, but the stacktrace should lead you to where the error is being generated.

Other issues in your tests are

1. You appear to be using a JS capable driver (capybara-webkit) but still have transactional testing enabled.  This leads to any objects you create in the test code (FactoryGirl, etc) not being visible to the app. See - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup - and then set up DatabaseCleaner using the recommended configuration from https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example.
2. Stop using `wait_for_ajax` - there are about 3 valid (and very rare) needs for anything like `wait_for_ajax`, anything else just isn't needed or points to terrible app design.  If you do need to wait before clicking a button for some request to finish then you should have an expectation for whatever visible change on the page indicates the request is done (Capybara automatically waits/retries on page content expectations) - If there is no visible change how is the user supposed to know when they can or cannot click the button?
3. You can't assume the id of an object you create will be any specific number - (/users/1) and hardcoding pathnames leads to brittle tests if you ever change the routing names.  Instead use the rails provided helpers to check the path.  So assuming you have created the user object as a variable called `user` - it would be

   ```
   expect(page).to have_current_path(user_path(user))
   ```

   That way if you ever change your routes to have the user path actually be /member/ all your tests don't break.

Comment: Thank you for response and your feedback about issues. Here is the whole error line  "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=" . Here id should be equal to 1, but after equals sign there is a blank. Why it is empty here? I would be grateful if you could give a hint

Comment: @A.B You don't show where you're creating the user (or calling visit) but it's most likely either #1 in my answer where the app code can't see the user you created in the test code due to transactional database testing, or it's because  you are just building the user rather than creating it.